# Python for each loop is not working

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm looping a list and inside that loop I'm looping some documents which are fetched from mongodb. But in the output console I can see only one iteration.
But the outer loop works fine. When I debug it goes inside the outer loop but doesn't go to the inner loop. Please help me out.

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
db = client['mydb']
documents = icps_db.user.find({})
name_set = ['john', 'marshal', 'ann' ...]

    for name in name_set:
        print(name)
        for idx, document in enumerate(documents):
            print (documents)
            if name in document["filtered_words"]:
                print ("Found " + name)
            else:
                print (name + " not found in document ")
```

Output
In the second iteration it doesn't reach line : print (str(idx)).

```
    john
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7faed0ad0910>
Found john
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7faed0ad0910>
john not found in document 
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7faed0ad0910>
Found john
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7faed0ad0910>
john not found in document 
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7faed0ad0910>
john not found in document 
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7faed0ad0910>
Found john
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7faed0ad0910>
john not found in document 
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7faed0ad0910>
Found john
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7faed0ad0910>
Found john
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7faed0ad0910>
john not found in document 
john
marshal
marshal
```

Comment: Are you sure `documents` is not empty? Perhaps print this collection first.

Comment: `documents` is probably empty.

Comment: documents is definitely empty

Comment: The document as mentioned by other is probably empty.

Comment: Since it is going in once, may be one element in the collection ?

Comment: `documents = icps_db.user.find({})` After you first set of iterations over `documents` the cursor is used up.  It's a read-once container.  You either need to cache the results or do `find()` inside the outer loop.  I'm not familiar with `mongodb`, but a changing the definition of `documents` to `documents = list(icps_db.user.find({}))` should make your problem go away.  The only way that wouldn't work is if each document has some sort of live callback that uses the cursor (which I doubt).

Comment: If that does not work, do `documents.rewind()` before your inner loop.  [`rewind`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.rewind)  According to the docs this will "Rewind this cursor to its unevaluated state.

Reset this cursor if it has been partially or completely evaluated. Any options that are present on the cursor will remain in effect. Future iterating performed on this cursor will cause new queries to be sent to the server, even if the resultant data has already been retrieved by this cursor."

Comment: @SteveRumbalski Thanks a lot. you are absolutely correct. I changed it to list(icps_db.user.find({}))

Comment: Thanks others for the prompt replies.

Comment: I have turned my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
documents = icps_db.user.find({})
```

After you first set of iterations over `documents` the cursor is used up. It's a read-once container. You either need to cache the results or do  do `documents.rewind()` before your inner loop.

To cache the results do:

```
documents = list(icps_db.user.find({}))
```

I don't really know MongoDB, so it's possible that each document has some sort of live callback that uses the cursor (I doubt it).  If so, simple caching won't work.

The other solution would be to use [`rewind()`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.rewind):

> Rewind this cursor to its unevaluated state.
>
> Reset this cursor if it has been partially or completely evaluated.
>   Any options that are present on the cursor will remain in effect.
>   Future iterating performed on this cursor will cause new queries to be
>   sent to the server, even if the resultant data has already been
>   retrieved by this cursor.

Use it like so:

```
for name in name_set:
    documents.rewind()
    for idx, document in enumerate(documents):
        ...
```